# How to compare two fields in android realm.io

Tags: android, realm

Model:

```
 public class Something extends RealmObject {
    private String firstField;
    private String secondField;
```

This is my query:

```
 RealmResults<Something> r = realm.where(Something.class)
            .notEqualTo("firstField","secondField")
            .findAll();
```

is this correct and will give me all the records where the two fields are different? or will it give me all the records where firstField is not equal to the String "secondField"?

If it is incorrect, how do I achieve the comparing of the two fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Christian from Realm here. It is the second option. That query will compare the field "firstField" to the string "secondField". Unfortunately there is no easy way to do what you want, but it is probably not a uncommon use case so it is something we will take a look at how to support more easily.

Currently you would have to do it by hand:

```
RealmResults<Something> r = realm.where(Something.class)
            .notEqualTo("firstField","secondField")
            .findAll();

for (Something obj : r) {
  if (!obj.getFirstField().equals(obj.getSecondField())) {
    // Handle object   
  }  
}
```

Comment: Apparently the feature exists (I don't know since when, I just got started with realm) because according to this answer, it works : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32463498/3535408 but I stumbled upon yours first. Could you update your answer for other that might be in the same situation than me ? Thanks !

Comment: Actually this question is slightly different. This is about comparing the values for two fields already in Realm, not comparing a field in Realm with a provided value (which is what the question you reference do).

Comment: Ah sorry ! I understand better now. Thank you!