# Check two fields with Realm database

Tags: android, realm

How can I create an `and` operation with Realm?

Example I have an object with day and month and I want to check both those fields values.

Something like :

```
 RealmResults<Event> toEdit = realm.where(Event.class)
        .equalTo("day", day)
        .and
        .equalTo("month", month)
        .findAll();
```

But as far as I can tell there is no `and` operator.

Thank you

Comment: Did you tried something such obvious like `equalTo(...).equalTo(...)` ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Multiple conditions are combined with And unless there's an `.or()` between them, so it's just:

```
 RealmResults<Event> toEdit = realm.where(Event.class)
        .equalTo("day", day)
        .equalTo("month", month)
        .findAll();
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my day.